# Can't get more than five concurrent connection to mysql

Tags: mysql

Can't get more than five concurrent connection to `mysql`.
 Also "`max_user_connections = 0`" & "`max_connections = 151`" .
 Not able to find the exact cause. Help me !

Answer (score 0):

By `five concurrent connections` do you mean `five applications` or `five concurrent actual MySQL connections`?
If your application is a multi-processing, one application could grab multiple MySQL connections.

Also, if the application doesn't properly close its database connections, those connections could linger around(occupying connection pool) until it is terminated by MySQL timeout values.

You can always check how many concurrent connections are alive by going into MySQL client and use `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` command and start debugging from there.